# ¿Como ejecutar la descarga de un PDF con fpdf al pulsar un botón?

Tags: php, fpdf

Tengo este código y necesito que se descargue el PDF solo al pulsar el botón.

Lo que ahora hace es que cuando entras en la página se descarga automáticamente.

Aquí dejo el código:

```
<?php 

echo '<h3>PDF</h3>';

function pdf(){
    require('fpdf/fpdf.php');
    ob_start();
    $pdf = new FPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
    $pdf->Output('fpdf-complete.pdf', 'D');
    ob_end_flush(); 
} ?>

<button type="button" id="boton" onclick="accionPDF()">PDF</button>


<script>
  function accionPDF(){
    var pdf = <?php echo pdf() ?>;
    window.location.href = 'pdf.php';
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Estas utilizando mal el método [Output](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm)

Comment: Hola Daniel, bienvenido a StackOverflow en español. Te recomiendo realizar el [tour] para que aprenadas como funciona la plataforma y de paso ganar tu primer medalla. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

#### Opción 1

Navegar al PDF:

- Creas un archivo, por ejemplo `index.php`, con el siguiente código:

  ```
  <h3>PDF</h3>
  <button type="button" id="boton" onclick="accionPDF()">Descargar PDF</button>

  <script>
    function accionPDF(){
      window.location.href = 'pdf.php';
    }
  </script>
  ```
- Creas un archivo `pdf.php` con el siguiente código:

  ```
  require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

  $pdf = new FPDF();
  $pdf->AddPage();
  $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
  $pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
  $pdf->Output();
  ```

---

#### Opción 2

Descargar el PDF sin abandonar la página:

- Creas un archivo, por ejemplo `index.php`, con el siguiente código:

  ```
  <h3>PDF</h3>
  <a href="pdf.php" target="_blank">Descargar PDF</a>
  ```
- Creas un archivo `pdf.php` con el siguiente código:

  ```
  require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

  $pdf = new FPDF();
  $pdf->AddPage();
  $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
  $pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
  $pdf->Output('D', 'fpdf-complete.pdf);
  ```